# Django authenticate method not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the default Django from `django.contrib.auth` authenticate() method to authenticate if the user exists. I am doing this right after the user registers. The user registers and their username, email, and password is inputted into the database, but when I call `authenticate(username=username, password=password)` it is returning `None` for some reason. The password is being stored as a hash and it is worth to note that I am using my own custom User model, but inheriting from `django.contrib.auth` User model.

Here's my view:

```
class RegisterView(SuccessMessageMixin, View):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'oauth/auth_form.html'
    success_message = "You have successfully created an account!"

    # Display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False) # Do not save to table yet

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            try:
                validate_password(password, user)

            except ValidationError as e:
                form.add_error('password', e)  # to be displayed with the field's errors
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            # Let's try to login the user
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                login(request, user)
                return redirect('http://google.com')


        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Why is it that the authenticate method is not working out for me?

Comment: This could be a transactional issue: `authenticate` tries to fetch the user that you are creating in the current transaction from the database. But there is no need to authenticate since you already have the user instance. Just log the bugger in ;)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ohh, so I can just login the user and redirect them?

Comment: Yup, that is if you have only one `AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND`. If you have more than that you have to specify which backend to log him in with ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L87))

Comment: After all, he just set his username and password. No need to check if they are correct. When he comes next time and isn't logged in, then authenticate!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, you're right. I don't know why many tutorials have the authenticate method right after we just authenticated...

Answer (score 0):

Although @schwobaseggl 's answer should solve your issue, i.e. "No need to authenticate, just login directly", I've done something very similar in one of my older projects and maybe it helps you.

Here the registration process automatically logged in the user, and we were using email tokens as password:

```
def get_or_create_user(mobile):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        user = UserModel(mobile=mobile, username=mobile)
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save()
    return user

...

class UserRegistrationAndLogin(View):
    ...

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        next_url = request.GET.get('next')
        if form.is_valid():
            entered_token = form.cleaned_data['otp']
            if entered_token == self.token:
                user = get_or_create_user(mobile=self.mobile)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(next_url or settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
            else:
                form.add_error('otp', 'OTP does not match!')
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form, 'mobile': self.mobile})
```